# Vim performs operations related to:! gcc%

Tags: gcc, vim

Question: I have written a C program in vim, such as a simple program that outputs "hello,world". At this time, I type "! gcc%" in the bottom line command mode to compile, but this operation does not output "hello,world", but displays "please press ENTER or other commands to continue" on the terminal. I want to know why there is no output "hello,world"？

Do: I tried press ENTER, but the terminal returned to the vim program.

Look forward to: output the results of the program

Comment: What is the question? What did you try?

Comment: What does `gcc` print when you run it from a terminal?

Comment: I have written a C program in vim, such as a simple program that outputs "hello,world". At this time, I type "! gcc%" in the bottom line command mode to compile, but this operation does not output "hello,world", but displays "please press ENTER or other commands to continue" on the terminal. I want to know why there is no output "hello,world". I tried press ENTER, but the terminal returned to the vim program.@romainl

Comment: I'm not sure if the gcc has been output, but the response I got was "please press ENTER or other commands to continue" on the terminal.@Friedrich

Comment: C programs have to be *compiled* before they can be *run*. GCC is a *compiler*, it *compiles* the program. It does not *run* the program. To run it, compile first and then type `./a.out` in your terminal or `:!./a.out` in Vim. If everything is correct, you will see your output. The prompt "Please press ENTER etc." comes from Vim so you can read the output (which is none, in the GCC case). Don't try to learn two new things (Vim and GCC) at the same time. Keep it simple!

Comment: I see, `!gcc %` only provides compilation function, so the terminal successfully completes compilation and displays "please press ENTER or other commands to continue" for the next step. If you want to complete the compilation and perform the operation, you have to execute `!gcc % && ./a.out` in the command mode at the bottom.

Comment: You got it. Now that that's sorted out, you may delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

As @Friedrich said, you have to compile the program before you run it.  Presuming you have `gcc` and `make` installed, the easiest way to compile C programs in Vim is with `:make`, which will invoke `make` and show the results.  To start out with, presuming you just have a single source file and no `Makefile`, you can just use

```
:make %:r
```

That instructs `Make` to build a an executable program whose name is the same as your source code without the `.c` extension.  The `%:r` is a shortcut for the filename being edited without the extension; if your filename is something short like `hello.c`, then it is probably easier to just avoid that special syntax and instead use:

```
:make hello
```

If you wanted to, you could then execute it from within Vim by using

```
:!./hello
```

or better yet, launch it in a new terminal window in Vim:

```
:terminal ./hello
```